# what number should replace the question mark in hexagon diagram?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

I'm trying to solve this problem from a book, but can't understand how it works. Why is 12 in the center? What should be the missing number?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Can you please post the name of the book where you found this? For content you did not create yourself, we require proper attribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing number is

> 8

This is because:

> The number in the center is the difference of the sum of the most left numbers and the sum of the most right numbers.
>
>  A: (6 + 15 + 19) - (7 + 11 + 10) = 40 - 28 = 12
>  B: (17 + 19 + 2) - (14 + 16 + 2) = 38 - 32 = 6
>  C: (7 + 11 + 5) - (3 + ? + 2) = 23 - 5 - ? = 18 - ? = 10
>  So ? is 8.